# Are the Raptor engines too numerous and close together on Booster 7?

Tags: rockets, launch

SpaceX is in the process of scaling up their highly successful re-usable Falcon first stage to a much larger version with more powerful engines for their Starship program.

These new Raptor engines will put out a lot more thrust than their predecessors, and there will be 33 of them.  This will involve burning a lot more fuel in a given amount of time.

One of the classic issues in engineering involving larger scale is **heat exchange**.

Is it possible the inner rings of Raptors may overheat before MECO (Main Engine Cutoff) ?
Could SpaceX be monitoring this potential situation with temperature sensors in their upcoming flight?

Comment: I'm not sure which answer you expect here. "No, they never took obvious things into account" "They never make test runs before launch" "There will be no sensors onboard, it's fire and forget" "There have been no simulations, it all is a big game of chance"

Comment: @asdfex we thought of everything, but that darn iceberg got in the way.  Just asking.  They've never flown 33 Raptors (or tested) before.

Comment: I wouldn't mind betting that they have thought very carefully about such eventualities and analysed them to death. Of course strange things sometimes happen, but I doubt anyone is going to out guess SpaceX

Comment: This seems somewhat poorly structured as a question. 'Do SpaceX monitor engine temperatures' is possibly answerable 'how does clustering engines effect heat flow' probably can also be but as written the only way to answer 'will inner ring heat faster than SpaceX expect' is to build a better thermal model of the booster than SpaceX has.

Comment: @asdfex I came here to emit sarcasm but it looks like you have it covered already

Comment: This would (probably) be a good question if you asked ‘how’ they monitored/simulated these things rather than asking if they do.

Comment: In the vein of sarcasm from a retired hi-tech design engineer... we would ignore using mechanical/structural finite element analysis, computational fluid dynamics analysis, thermal finite element analysis, finite differences analysis. We wouldn't build tech demonstration platforms to test. We'd just risk tons of money to build a huge system on the premise "lets see if this doesn't blow up".

Comment: A "high tech design engineer" should know that "computational analysis" involves programming what you **think** will happen.  So, you can wind up believing your own simulations (circular logic) while something critical may have been missed.  As far as "let's see if this doesn't blow up" ahem, maybe SpaceX will hire you.

Comment: @BradV  "lets see if this doesn't blow up" is a perfectly valid approach as long as you're in sandbox mode and don't have any kerbals on board :)

Comment: modern design simulation via computer modeling is a loop of simulate, correlate, adapt modeling, simulate, correlate, adapt modeling some more, and so on. I was not involved with modeling/analysing rocket motors, just avionics. I would hazard a guess that folks doing the rocket work are drawing on quite a lot of history of what does and does not give good analysis results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible the inner rings of Raptors may overheat before MECO? Yes. Possible.

A more interesting question is “what will happen then?” If a few engines are shut down, no problem. But if an inner ring engine disassembles, there is a possibility of a failure chain reaction. This was a significant contributor to the failure of the N-1

[image]

[image]

Of the two picture above, one is the ill-fated N-1 and one is SpaceX’s booster. Below is a Saturn V

[image]

Rocket engines have lots of passages containing highly pressurized propellants. And they are hot.  Cluster them tighter, and center engines get hotter. Failure of a central engine is more likely to start a chain reaction conflagration than an outer ring engine.

Lots of plumbing:

[image]

Mission failure modes are different for single engine (ARIANE) than a multi-engine (SpaceX) booster. Maybe there is a Goldilocks number that minimizes both the risk of engine shut-down on one hand, and and conflagration on the other. I guess that number is around 5.

Comment: If the coloured picture is SpaceX's booster, doesn't it look like the outer ring engines would have more chance in overheating one another than overheating the inner ring ?

Comment: @Cornelis  ... the second picture (30 thrusters) is the N-1. it scored zero out of 4 and created what may be the largest non-nuclear explosion in history. Conflagration contributed to this record. The raptors (two monochrome photos) are packed even closer.

Comment: The spacing of the inner ring engines are different in the two monochrome photos. I think it's good practice to mention the sources of the images, both for crediting and verification.

Comment: @Cornelis: The lower image seems to be the already outdated version with 29 Raptor V1.5 (or even V1) engines (20 on the outer ring, 9 in the center). Current boosters have 33 Raptor V2 engines with 13 in the center, organized in a cluster of 3 and a ring of 10, and still 20 on the outer ring.

Answer (score 1):

There is a qualitative way to find maximum or minimum of the sum of two functions. The rule of thumb is that the max (or min) is where the two functions are equal.

[image]

We assume the risk of mission loss for unscheduled engine shutdown is finite if there is only one engine (depending on when in the planned burn it shuts down). This risk falls dramatically with increasing engine number.

Likewise we assume that the risk of mission failure from conflagration is zero with one engine (there is nowhere for the fire to spread. So no conflagration).

The minimum of the sum of both risks is where they are equal.

From this, we can make the generalization that the more reliable your engines are. the less you should use. And the more fire resistant they are, the more you should use.

I hope SpaceX has made all that plumbing real fire resistant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the risk of failure is larger for a two-engine setup compared to a one-engine setup. For most of the flight you have twice the probability of engine failure, but are not able to achieve orbit with just 50% thrust available.

Comment: @asdfex ... You're right. But if you look at it from the other way (time to main engine shutdown), the period during which failure of one engine will result in mission failure is shorter. I'm not sure how the two risks balance out. And it is possible for the remaining engine to burn longer, using the fuel that is not being consumed by the failed engine.